# adfs 3.0 custom attribute store dynamic claim types

Tags: claims-based-identity, adfs, claims, adfs3.0

In our ADFS 3.0 we have a custom attribute-store that communicates with a rest-service to retrieve specific attributes based on the userid. These attributes comes with an urn and a value. My goal was to have the urn retrieved from the rest-service set to the claim-type but this type seems to be set in the so called template you create from the gui of ADFS. See below code:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname"]
=> issue(store = "Custom_AttributeStore", types = ("my:custom:urn"), query = "dummyString", param = c.Value);
```

Is it possible with adfs claim rule language to set the claim types programmatically in my custom attributestore?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to dynamically emit any pair of claim type and value from a custom attribute store. [This article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16170.ad-fs-2-0-dynamic-claim-types.aspx) helped me to figure it out.

Your custom attribute store needs to return a single column of string values, where each value represents a single claim type and its corresponding value, separated by a special character (a semicolon in this example):

```cs
public string[][] EndExecuteQuery(IAsyncResult result)
{
    ...
    return new[]
    {
        new[] { "http://example/custom-type-1;Value 1" },
        new[] { "http://example/custom-type-2;Value 2" },
        ...
    };  
}
```

Next, use a custom claim rule to retrieve values from your custom attribute store and create input claims of an arbitrary type from them. Use the `add` command (which creates input claims) instead of the `issue` command (which creates output claims).

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"] => add(store = "YourCustomAttributeStore", types = ("custom-type-value-pair"), query = "YourQuery", param = c.Value);
```

Finally, use another custom claim rule to pick up each of the input claims created in the previous step and use their values to issue the proper output claims. The `RegexReplace` function can be used to separate type and value.

```
c:[Type == "custom-type-value-pair"] => issue(Type = RegexReplace(c.Value, ";.*$", ""), Value = RegexReplace(c.Value, "^.*?;", ""));
```

It may be a little convoluted, but it works.